# Tensor products of rings as modules over themselves

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring, and, consider the tensor product $$R \otimes_R R $$ where we consider the 'first $R$' as a right module over $R$ and the 'second $R$' as a left module over itself.

Now, I've seen that $R \otimes_R R \cong R$, but I'm not sure why? How would I prove this? I've tried:

Define an $R$-middle-linear ($R$-balanced) map $m(a,b) = ab$ from $R \times R \rightarrow R$, but I'm not too sure where to go from here?

Comment: In general $M_R\otimes {_R}R_R\cong M_R$ and ${_R}R_R\otimes_R {_R}M\cong {_R}M$. Apply either one with $M=R$. E.g., for the first one: the map $M\otimes R \to M$ induced by $(m,r)\mapsto mr$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

That gives you one direction, namely $R\otimes_RR\to R$. 
*If* $R$ has an identity element, then its inverse will be $r\mapsto 1\otimes r$. 
Note that, by the tensor property, we have
$$ab\otimes 1=a\otimes (b\cdot 1) =a\otimes b=(1\cdot a)\otimes b=1\otimes ab$$